# Converting value from Pyspark Row datetime.date to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to fetch data from a table that returns a list of Row datetime.date objects. I would like to have them as a list of Varchar/String values.

```
query = "select device_date from device where device is not null"
res = spark.sql(query).collect()

if len(res) != 0:
    return res[:20]
```

The returned value seems to be of format

```
[Row(device_date =datetime.date(2019, 9, 25)), Row(device_date =datetime.date(2019, 9, 17)), Row(device_date =datetime.date(2020, 1, 8))]
```

I would like to have the following output returned instead:

```
['2019-09-25','2019-09-17','2020-01-08']
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to collect your data and then have to process them using python ?

With `df = spark.sql(query)`, depending on the answer :

## YES (python solution)

```py
out = df.collect()

list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strftime(x.device_date, "%Y-%m-%d"), out))

['2019-09-25', '2019-09-17', '2020-01-08']

# OR

list(map(str, (x.device_date for x in out)))
['2019-09-25', '2019-09-17', '2020-01-08']
```

## NO (Spark solution)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(F.date_format("device_date", "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("device_date")).collect()
                                                                       
[Row(device_date='2019-09-25'),
 Row(device_date='2019-09-17'),
 Row(device_date='2020-01-08')]
```

---

The spark version can also be done directly in SQL :

```
query = "select date_format(device_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date_format from device"

spark.sql(query).collect()

[Row(date_format='2019-09-25'),
 Row(date_format='2019-09-17'),
 Row(date_format='2020-01-08')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `date_format` function beforehand.
Here is the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html), but basically:

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format
>>> df.select(date_format('device_date', 'YYYY-mm-dd').alias('date')).collect()
[Row(date='2015-04-08')]
```

Also please be careful, it seems like your column name: `"device_date "` has a space at the end. That could be making your life harder.